# Building a library for consumption that uses requirejs?

Tags: coffeescript, javascript, requirejs

I have a question that I can't seem to find an answer to. I'm currently building a library for consumption and I want to use requirejs to make it more modular. I have the following project structure...

```
- example
    - scripts
        - otter
            - libs
                - signals
                    signals.js
            - modules
                subModule1.js
                subModule2.js
            otter.js
    index.htm

- src
    - libs (copied to example folder at build time)
        - signals
            signals.js
    - modules
        subModule1.coffee
        subModule2.coffee
    - otter.coffee
```

What I want to do is be able to require the signals.js file, and any of my modules, from any of my other files without requiring a path to be setup in require, or without me having to know about how the project is setup at development time.

For example, what I've attempted to do in my otter.coffee file is this:

```
define ['/libs/signals/signals'], (signals) ->
    # I've also tried './libs/signals/signals' and 'libs/signals/signals'
```

This doesn't seem to work as require can't find the signals.js file.

How can I get requirejs to load modules relative to the current file? I've read that I can ask for require as a dependency and that the path for that require will be set to the path of the file, but that doesn't seem to work either. It throws a not loaded yet error i:e -

```
define (require) ->
    signals = require './libs/signals/signals'
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Do I need to change the structure of my library? Do I have to force a specific structure? Do I ask those who use it to include certain paths in their require config?

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT** -

I've noticed that if I alias my library inside my main.js file for require, the require (through require or define) of signals doesn't work (keep getting 404 not found). However, if I don't alias my library everything works fine..

For example, if my require main.js file has..

```
...
paths: {
    'otter': 'scripts/otter/otter'
}
...
```

then the require of signals fails. However, if I don't have the path and I require otter through it's direct path, the require of signal works. I'm requiring signal like this in otter.js ...

```
define (require) ->
    signals = require './libs/signals/signals'
```

It this a bug with require.js?

Comment: 2 things: why don't you want to set up a path in require? Is the signals.js the only file in your lib? Or is it the whole otter project?

Comment: re getting a _not loaded yet error_ keep in mind that `require`s are asyncronous.  Try: `require("./lib/signals/signals", function(signals) { ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequireJS uses two functions to do its job: `define()` and `require()`.

My understanding is that `define()` lists dependencies and only loads modules; loading dependencies that are not modules (*those who not use `define()`*) is done with `require()`.

Because only modules can load modules, there have to be someone else to load the first module. In your case, to use `signals.js` in `otter.js` the first has to be a module and the second has to use `require()`. I guess that a `require()` is always needed before any `define()` uses.

**otter.js:**

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'signals': 'libs/signals/signals',
    'module1': 'modules/subModule1'
  }
});

require(['signals'], function(signals) {
  signals.initialize();
});
```

**signals.js:**

```
define(['module1'], function(module) {
  return {
    initialize: function() {
      module.doStuff();
    }
  }
});
```

**subModule1.js:**

```
define([], function() {
  return {
    doStuff: function() {
      console.log('hello world');
    }
  }
});
```

*ps. Loading modules relative to the current file do not seems to be allowed: [a `baseUrl` property](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl) is used to configure every modules paths in `requirejs.config()`.*

Comment: Thank you for this yves. I was afraid the answer was "I can't use relative paths". I want to avoid forcing people who use my library to add a path to their require config. Any ideas of the best way to handle that?

Comment: I would advice you to not deliver a bunch of files but compress your library into one file; requirejs have [good resources](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs) to do that. Doing so, your customers are not forced to use requirejs.

Comment: One last thing, if your library needs lazy loading — resources loaded only on demand — requirejs [also offers resources](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject) to build static, requirejs free, files.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm not sure how I missed both those tools. I guess I should of read the require docs a bit more closely, lol.. Anyways, this is the way I'm going to go (combining everything into one file, both with and without require). Thanks for the answer!